# Reference a class instance to be created in a different Python class

Tags: python-3.x

I have a project that is split into 3 files.
The first one is the file containing some API classes and most importantly `SQLConnection` class.
The second file contains all the data structure and data logic in the class `Data`
The third file is all of the higher level logic and operations with data.
An oversimplification of my project:

```
"""Contents of file1"""
import pandas as pd
import getpass
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class SQLConnection:
    def __init__(self,user,hostname,db,):
        self.user = user
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.db = db
        pword = getpass.getpass("Enter password for user {}".format(user))
        engine = create_engine("mysql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(user,pword,hostname,db))
        self.cnx = engine.connect()

    def write_to_db(self, df, table_name):
        try:
            df.to_sql(table_name,con = self.cnx,if_exists='append',index=False)
        except Exception as e:
            print("\n \n")
            print(df,"\n", e)
            pass


"""Contents of file2"""
# Dependancies:
import pandas as pd
# Local imports:
from file1 import SQLConnection

class Data:
    schema = ['col1','col2']
    def __init__(self,foo,bar):
        self.arg1 = foo
        self.arg2 = bar
        df = pd.DataFrame([[self.arg1,self.arg2]],columns = Data.schema)
        """ !!! THIS will not work because i need to access the instance !!! """
        SQLConnection.write_to_db(df,'Data')


"""Contents of file3"""
# Local imports:
from file2 import Data

entry = Data(foo="something",bar="something else")
```

I have a problem with the fact that i need to use the instance of `SQLConnection` in the `__init__()` of a the `Data` class. I thought about maybe instantiating `SQLConnection` in file3 and then somehow passing it down to `Data` but i did not find much reference material for how to do that.
**I would need either a way to pass an instance of a class to a different class or a way to circumvent this problem**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way I can think of to do this is simply pass the `SQLConnection` instance in the `Data` constructor:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, conn):
        ...
        conn.write_to_db....
```

And in file 3:

```
from file1 import SQLConnection
from file2 import Data

conn = SqlConnection(...)
entry = Data(foo="something",bar="something else", conn=conn)
```

Comment: Thanks! This will probably work just as i need it to and i have no idea why i didnt think of it.